# Access Violation Exception in Forms.ShowDialog

Tags: c#, winforms

I get an `AccessViolationException` every time I call the `ShowDialog()` Method of a Form I created. The problem occurs only when the `CheckkedListBox` `moduleOperationsBox` contains Elements. There are other elements of type `ListBox` that work just fine.

Here the corresponding code parts:

The ShowDialog() Call:

```
public new System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult ShowDialog()
{
    foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> foo in obsoleteOperations)
    {
        moduleOperationsBox.Items.Add(foo);
    }                   
    return base.ShowDialog();
}
```

Related parts of the Constructor:

```
public ModuleSyncDialog(EA.Repository rep)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    obsoleteOperations = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

    this.moduleOperationsBox.DisplayMember = "Key";
    this.moduleOperationsBox.ValueMember = "Value";                   
}
```

Method to fill the List:

```
public void addModuleOperation(string name, string guid)
{
    obsoleteOperations.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(name,guid));
}
```

and the StackTrace:

```
   bei System.Drawing.SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.GdipDrawRectangleI(HandleRef graphics, HandleRef pen, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height)
   bei System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pen pen, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.ControlPaint.DrawFlatCheckBox(Graphics graphics, Rectangle rectangle, Color foreground, Brush background, ButtonState state)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.ControlPaint.DrawFlatCheckBox(Graphics graphics, Rectangle rectangle, ButtonState state)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.ControlPaint.DrawCheckBox(Graphics graphics, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height, ButtonState state)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.ControlPaint.DrawCheckBox(Graphics graphics, Rectangle rectangle, ButtonState state)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox.OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.WmReflectDrawItem(Message& m)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.WndProc(Message& m)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox.WndProc(Message& m)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.SendMessage(HandleRef hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.SendMessage(Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.ReflectMessageInternal(IntPtr hWnd, Message& m)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmOwnerDraw(Message& m)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmDrawItem(Message& m)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc(IntPtr wndProc, IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DefWndProc(Message& m)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.DefWndProc(Message& m)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.WndProc(Message& m)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox.WndProc(Message& m)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Application.RunDialog(Form form)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog()
   bei ModelAssistant.ModuleSyncDialog.ShowDialog() in C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\ostwal99\Eigene Dateien\EA_EXTENSIONS\EA_ADDIN\src\AEPAddIn\ModelAssistant\ModuleSyncDialog.designer.cs:Zeile 524.
   bei ModelAssistant.ModelAssistant.synchronizeInterface(Repository repository, Element eaInterface) in C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\ostwal99\Eigene Dateien\EA_EXTENSIONS\EA_ADDIN\src\AEPAddIn\ModelAssistant\ModelAssistant.cs:Zeile 436.
   bei ModelAssistant.ModelAssistant.EA_OnNotifyContextItemModified(Repository repository, String guid, ObjectType ot) in C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\ostwal99\Eigene Dateien\EA_EXTENSIONS\EA_ADDIN\src\AEPAddIn\ModelAssistant\ModelAssistant.cs:Zeile 188.
   bei AEPAddInHost.AEPAddInHost.EA_OnNotifyContextItemModified(Repository repository, String guid, ObjectType ot) in C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\ostwal99\Eigene Dateien\EA_EXTENSIONS\EA_ADDIN\src\AEPAddIn\AEPAddInHost\AEPAddInHost.cs:Zeile 151.
```

It was compiled with VS2010 under WindowsXP SP3, .Net Framework 4.

Would be really nice if you post any ideas to solve the problem or need additional Information.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you calling `ShowDialog` on a thread other than the main UI thread?

Comment: @PeterRitchie Actually the Code is part of an AddIn for another Program. It is a com registered dll. When certain events occur a function of my dll is called. I do not create any other threads.

Comment: Is this particular callback supposed to be showing UI?

Comment: Knowing more about this other program would be really helpful in our ability to offer help.

Comment: I definitely need to use some UI to gather information from the user. The Program calling my dll is Enterprise Architect. .Net and Windows.Forms are supported. Everything works fine as long as i don't use a CheckedListBox. When I use a ListBox instead i do not get an Exception.